# Getting an object property value using a dotted string

Tags: javascript

I m trying to access an object property through a string.

What I m trying to do is :

```
const data = {
    key: {
        subKey: 'value'
    }
};

const theString = 'key.subKey';

function accessPropFromString(obj, stringCall) {
    // I don't know what to put on here
}

console.log(accessPropFromString(data, theString)) // prints 'value'
```

I absolutely don't know how to make that happen...

How can I do this kind of stuff with JavaScript ?

Comment: You're not new here.  You know the routine.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use template literals instead: ``const theString = `${key.subKey}`;``

Comment: @trincot: what if the value in question is not a string?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, then use a tag function: ``((_, val) => val)`${data.key.subKey}`;``

Answer (score 4):

You could split the path and reduce the object.

```js
const getValue = (object, path) => path.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object),
      data = { key: { subKey: 'value' } },
      theString = 'key.subKey';

console.log(getValue(data, theString));
```

Comment: I think this is as good as it's likely to get given that we're starting with a single string.  There's an API problem in that it won't handle properties whose names contain a `'.'`, but that's intrinsic to the question.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, right, an array as parameter would be better for strings with dots.

Comment: Yes, and when I [dealt with this](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) in my library, I reluctantly went with an array.  I like the simplicity of such strings, but there were too many counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Assuming, you have fixed format.

```
function accessPropFromString(obj, stringCall) {
   var splitter =stringCall.split(".");
   return data[splitter[0]][splitter[1]];
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/hbrqn0mh/1/)

Comment: what do you do with another level?

Comment: Yes, not very generic.

Answer (score 1):

See comments inline:

```js
const data = {
    key: {
        subKey: 'value'
    }
};

const theString = 'key.subKey';

function accessPropFromString(obj, stringCall) {
    // Split the string into individual parts
    var parts = stringCall.split(".");
    
    // You can use strings to lookup properties on objects
    // if you use bracket notation, like this;
    // parts["key"]["subKey"]
    // So, parts[0] will be "key" and parts[1] will be "subKey"
    return obj[parts[0]][parts[1]];
}

console.log(accessPropFromString(data, theString)) // prints 'value'
```

Comment: What happens with additional levels?

Comment: @ScottSauyet You're right, it doesn't handle that. I was really just demonstrating how bracket-notation should be used to access properties with strings.  By the way, how are you? ;)